# How to insert the date in dd-mm-yyy format in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, date-format

I have a problem entering the date; I have a form consisting of prodcode, name and date (where the latter has been saved as a String).
I try to test it with Postman by inserting the following example fields:
{
"prodcode": "PC001",
"name": "Personal Computer",
"date": "11/23/2020"
}

and when I go to save it in the db I get the following error:

*Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '23 -11-2020 'for column' data 'at row 1*

This is the code of interest:

*Product.java*

```js
package com.example.Model; 

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.example.Model.Product;


@Entity
@Table(name="productprove")
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String prodcode; 
    private String name; 
    
    private String date;
    

      public Product() {
      }

      public Product(String prodcode, String name) {
          super();
          this.prodcode = prodcode;
          this.name = name;
      }

    public String getProdcode() {
        return prodcode;
    }

    public void setProdcode(String prodcode) {
        this.prodcode = prodcode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

*Controller.java*

```js
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private Product_Service productservice;
    
    @PostMapping("save-product")
    public boolean saveProduct(@RequestBody Product product) throws IOException, ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy"); //Format for input
        String date=product.getDate();
        java.util.Date dn = dateParser.parse(date); //Parsing the date
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy"); //Format for output
        product.setDate(dateFormatter.format(dn)); //Printing the date
         return productservice.saveProduct(product);
    }
```

I would like to know if the way I thought of it is right or if other changes need to be made.

Heartfelt thanks to those who will help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use date instead of string for the date. and use @DateTimeFormat

```
@Entity
@Table(name="productprove")
public class Product {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;
```

I hope that will works.